# Automatic language layout change for some windows

Tags: kde, language-support, plasma

In a KDE window frame:
[image]

And then:
[image]

In which some settings can be applied; for example automatic sending of this application's windows to a virtual desktop.

I'm looking for a setting in a similar way that automatically changes language layout to Russian for all windows which contain 'aarvark' in title bar. So any window with a title which contains 'aardvark' as a substring, when clicked (=focused), will change language layout to Russian.